# How to parse an XYZ file into 3 separate files based on Z value?

Tags: python, parsing, xyz

I have an [XYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_file_format) file in the following format:

| X[m] | Y[m] | DensA_1050c[m] | DensB_1200c[m] | DensC_1250c[m] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.77 | 12.98 | 13.17 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.77 | 12.98 | 13.17 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.77 | 12.98 | 13.17 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.77 | 12.98 | 13.17 |

I am looking for a way to read in the XYZ file in python and then re-write the XYZ file into 3 separate XYZ files like such:

**DensA_1050c[m]**

| X[m] | Y[m] | Z[m] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.77 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.77 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.77 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.77 |

**DensB_1200c[m]**

| X[m] | Y[m] | Z[m] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.98 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.98 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.98 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 12.98 |

**DensC_1250c[m]**

| X[m] | Y[m] | Z[m] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 13.17 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 13.17 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 13.17 |
| 627841.54 | 231758.7 | 13.17 |

I've tried the following code to read in the XYZ file which works, but I don't know how to parse it to be like the above examples.

```
import numpy as np

file_location = 'C:/Users/Public/AllData.xyz'
xyz_file = np.genfromtxt(fname=file_location, skip_header=2, dtype='unicode')

print(xyz_file)
```

The result from the above code is:

```
['627201.81' '233336.97' '12.94' '13.27' '13.41']
```

Comment: Since there's no formal standard for the XYZ format, you should add a short sample of the contents of the file you have to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is very closely tailored to your problem. The row headers which are used for the output file names are hard-coded and mapped to the corresponding column index.

```
import numpy as np

file_location = 'AllData.xyz'
xyz_file = np.genfromtxt(fname=file_location, skip_header=2, dtype='unicode')

mappings = { 'DensA_1050c.xyz': 2, 'DensB_1200c.xyz' : 3, 'DensC_1250c.xyz' : 4 }

for mapping in mappings:
    with open(mapping, 'w') as output_file:
        for record in xyz_file:
            output_file.write(record[0])
            output_file.write('\t')
            output_file.write(record[1])
            output_file.write('\t')
            output_file.write(record[mappings[mapping]])
            output_file.write('\n')
```

DensA_1050c.xyz

```
627841.54   231758.7    12.77
627841.54   231758.7    12.77
627841.54   231758.7    12.77
627841.54   231758.7    12.77
```

DensB_1200c.xyz

```
627841.54   231758.7    12.98
627841.54   231758.7    12.98
627841.54   231758.7    12.98
627841.54   231758.7    12.98
```

DensC_1250c.xyz

```
627841.54   231758.7    13.17
627841.54   231758.7    13.17
627841.54   231758.7    13.17
627841.54   231758.7    13.17
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain to me what the ```for record in xyz_file:``` loop is doing?